# Percorrer um array onde o índice é uma Data

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Como eu faço para percorrer um *Array* onde o índice é uma data que varia a cada consulta no Banco de Dados.

Só um detalhe, as datas são **dinâmicas** a cada consulta.

O *Array* chega dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [2018-04-07] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28498
        )

    [2018-04-08] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28498
        )

    [2018-05-05] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28762
        )

    [2018-05-06] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28762
        )

    [2018-06-16] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28765
        )

    [2018-06-17] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28765
        )

    [2018-07-06] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28764
        )

    [2018-07-07] => Array
        (
            [ConteudoId] => 28764
        )

)
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $data => $valor) { ... }`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss As datas são dinâmicas

Comment: Mas isso não faz diferença.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e como eu pego [ConteudoId]?

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

**Exemplo:**

```
 $array = array("2018-04-07" => array("conteudoid" => "a"),  
              "2018-04-08" => array("conteudoid" => "b"),
              "2018-04-09" => array("conteudoid" => "c"));

   foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     echo "$key => $value[conteudoid] \n";
   }
```

**Resultado:**

```
2018-04-07 => a 
2018-04-08 => b 
2018-04-09 => c
```

[Documentação - Foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

Percorrendo com um **foreach**

Ex:

```
foreach ($arrayBanco as $chave => $valor) {
    echo $valor['conteudoID'];
}
```

Note que no seu código cada posição do array principal, retorna outro array, que é onde você encontra o **conteudoID** que você precisa, então basta fazer como o exemplo acima para acessar o valor **$valor['conteudoID'];**